# What should I put into FindAppointmentsAsync's &self parameter?

Tags: windows, rust

I'm new to rust and am trying to make use of the `windows` cargo. But I don't understand what I should set the `&self` parameter in the `FindAppointmentsAsync` function.

This is Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "rust-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]


[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.43.0"
features = [
    "ApplicationModel",
    "ApplicationModel_Appointments",
    "Foundation_Collections",
]
```

This is main.rs:

```rs
use std::time::Duration;

use windows::{
    core::*, ApplicationModel::Appointments::*, Foundation::{DateTime, TimeSpan},
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let rangestart = DateTime::default();
    let rangelength = TimeSpan::from(Duration::new(60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 0));
    println!("test");

    unsafe {
        let store = AppointmentStore();
        let result = AppointmentStore::FindAppointmentsAsync(&store, rangestart, rangelength);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

If `let store = AppointmentStore::new();` the error is `no function or associated item named 'new' found`

If `let store = AppointmentStore();`, the error is `expected 1 argument, found 0`

If `let store = AppointmentStore("");` the error is `cannot initialize a tuple struct which contains private fields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an `AppointmentStore` directly, as it has private fields and does not expose a constructor function.

Looking at [the docs](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/ApplicationModel/Appointments/struct.AppointmentStore.html?search=AppointmentStore#method.FindAppointmentsAsync), there are two ways to get an `AppointmentStore`:

- By calling `clone` on an existing one.
- By calling `RequestStoreAsync` on an `AppointmentManager` or `AppointmentManagerForUser`.

`AppointmentManager` is a struct with no fields, so you can create one by simply doing:

```rust
let foo = AppointmentManager;
let bar = foo.RequestStoreAsync(/* insert params here */);
```

`AppointmentManagerForUser` also cannot be constructed directly, and  is obtained by calling `GetForUser` on an AppointmentManager.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't have errors anymore by creating the AppointmentStore using RequestStoreAsync like this: `let store = AppointmentManager::RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType::AppCalendarsReadWrite).unwrap().await.unwrap();`. The issue has been resolved!